# C# XAML ScrollViewer to work without MaxHeight

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a grid that further down have a StackPanel. I have defined the row's height for the last to be "*", and in this very last row, is where the StackPanel and all the control would inhabit.

So I have the bellow code in XAML for my StackPanel

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="333">
        <StackPanel MaxHeight="333">
        <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="333">
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblRouteDetail" FontSize="35" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Well, it worked, only that I have to constraint that the MaxHeight is 333, without that, it won't work; the ScrollViewer won't work, the content in the TextBlock wouldn't be scrollable.

Could you state where is my problem, and how to fix this things up?

Answer (score 2):

A `StackPanel`, unless set to a specific height (or width if its orientation is set to `Horizontal`), does not constrain the height of its children, but is sized according to them. If you want to scroll your controls, you could either keep the `MaxHeight` property or use a different panel for holding them, such as a `Grid` or a `DockPanel`.

Comment: yeah. I remember. I read a book that he, the author, got something to do with orientation. well, why not he explained that better... and what's DockPanel, I just heard it. anyway. let me try now.

Comment: well... I have try about the orientation, and it still is not working. which StackPanel do you mean actually, because I have 2 StackPanels.

Comment: As I said, just ditch the StackPanels and use a more appropriate panel, such as a Grid or a DockPanel. You can [have a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_main_UI_elements) to familiarize yourself with the various panel types.

Comment: So bad that I think it has something to do with MaxWeight, or Weight. It just an inch for the solution I guess. And, DockPanel is not available. Or it is? because I am coding for Windows 8 Modern App.